# Как выровнять текст с правой стороны?

Tags: css

Имеется текст, сейчас он прилегает к иконке слева, а нужно чтобы текст был прижат вправо, но чтобы свойство `text-align` было `left`. Как это сделать?
При этом на мобилках предполагается, что эти три колонки будут на всю ширину, тогда лучше, чтобы текст был прижат влево
сейчас так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
нужно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.specifications {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 500px;
    flex-basis: 500px;
}
.specifications__item {
    width: 33%;
    flex-basis: 33%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.specifications__item > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.specifications__icon {
    width: 39px;
    flex-basis: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.specifications__title {

}
.specifications__title span {

}
```

```html
<div class="specifications">
  <div class="specifications__item">
    <span class="specifications__icon"></span>
    <span class="specifications__title"><span>Бесплатный  монтаж</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="specifications__item">
    <span class="specifications__icon"></span>
    <span class="specifications__title"><span>Редуктор  давления</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="specifications__item">
    <span class="specifications__icon"></span>
    <span class="specifications__title"><span>Комплект картриджей</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q40f178a/

Comment: Зачем вам "text-align было left"? Чтобы на мобилках он был left?

Comment: text-align должен быть left как на десктопе, так и на мобилках, но на десктопе текст должен быть прижатым вправо своей колонки

Comment: Так почему бы в @media не прописать прижимание к левой части?

Comment: @Antonio112009, всмысле, сейчас и так прижимается к левой части

Comment: Я к тому, что в `.specifications__title` прописать прижиматься к правой части, а в `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) ` прописать `.specifications__title` - `text-align:left`

Comment: @Antonio112009, посмотрите на картинку, если будет text-align: right, то на десктопе, к примеру в первой колонке слово "монтаж" будет прижато вправо, а этого не нужно. Вы ведь должны знать, что такое text-align: right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал margin-left;

Про `flex: 0 0 39px` можно прочесть тут - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794713/how-can-i-have-two-fixed-width-columns-with-one-flexible-column-in-the-center)

```css
.specifications {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 440px;
}
.specifications__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.specifications__item > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.specifications__icon {
    /* width: 39px; */
    flex: 0 0 39px;
    height: 39px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.specifications__title {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.specifications__title span {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="specifications">
  <div class="specifications__item">
    <span class="specifications__icon"></span>
    <span class="specifications__title"><span>Бесплатный  монтаж</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="specifications__item">
    <span class="specifications__icon"></span>
    <span class="specifications__title"><span>Редуктор  давления</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="specifications__item">
    <span class="specifications__icon"></span>
    <span class="specifications__title"><span>Комплект картриджей</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```